# How to apply a pandas geocode function to Pyspark column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, geocode

Table is like this

| id | ADDRESS |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 6101 SUMMITVIEW AVE STE 200 YAKIMA |
| 1 | 527 CEDAR WAY SUITE 105 OAKMONT |
| 2 | 1700 N ROSE AVE SUITE 460 OXNARD |
| 3 | 1275 YORK AVE NEW YORK |
| 4 | 2300 MANCHESTER EXPY A SUITE 101 A COLUMBUS |
| 5 | 401 N MICHIGAN AVE CHICAGO |
| 6 | 111 GROSSMAN DR INTERNAL MEDICINE BRAINTREE |
| 7 | 1850 N CENTRAL AVE STE 1600 PHOENIX |
| 8 | 47 NEW SCOTLAND AVENUE ALBANY MEDICAL CENTER A... |
| 9 | 201 N VINE ST EL DORADO |
| 10 | 4420 LAKE BOONE TRL RALEIGH |
| 11 | 2727 W HOLCOMBE BLVD HOUSTON |
| 12 | 850 PETER BRYCE BLVD TUSCALOOSA |
| 13 | 1803 WEHRLI RD NAPERVILLE |
| 14 | 4321 N MACDILL AVE STE 203 TAMPA |
| 15 | 111 CONTINENTAL DR SUITE 412 NEWARK |
| 16 | 1834 E INNOVATION PARK DR ORO VALLEY |
| 17 | 880 KEMPSVILLE RD SUITE 2200 NORFOLK |
| 18 | 701 PRINCETON AVE SW BIRMINGHAM |
| 19 | 4729 COUNTY ROAD 101 MINNETONKA |

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import folium
from folium.plugins import FastMarkerCluster
locator = Nominatim(user_agent="myGeocoder")
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
geocode = RateLimiter(locator.geocode,min_delay_seconds=0.0, error_wait_seconds=1.0, swallow_exceptions=True, return_value_on_exception=None)
apprix_1_na['location'] = apprix_1_na['ADDRESS'].apply(geocode)
apprix_1_na['point'] = apprix_1_na['location'].apply(lambda loc: tuple(loc.point) if loc enter code hereelse None)
```

I want this code to work in Pyspark for longitude and latitude

Comment: Since you are using `apply` on a pandas dataframe, I think in pyspark you can exploit [Pandas UDFs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'll show a "complex" example with GoogleV3 API. It is easy suitable to your case

```
from geopy.geocoders       import GoogleV3
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types     import FloatType, ArrayType

df = spark.createDataFrame([("123 Fake St, Springfield, 12345, USA",),("1000 N West Street, Suite 1200 Wilmington, DE 19801, USA",)], ["address"])

df.display()
```

| address |
| --- |
| 123 Fake St, Springfield, 12345, USA |
| 1000 N West Street, Suite 1200 Wilmington, DE 19801, USA |

```
@udf(returnType=ArrayType(FloatType())) 
def geoloc(address):
  api = 'your_api_key_here'
  geolocator = GoogleV3(api)
  
  #get lat_long
  return geolocator.geocode(address)[1]

#find coord
df = df.withColumn('geocode', geoloc(col('address')))

#separate tuple
df = df.withColumn("latitude", col('geocode').getItem(0))\
       .withColumn("longitude", col('geocode').getItem(1))

df.display()
```

| address | geocode | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 Fake St, Springfield, 12345, USA | [44.046238, -123.022026] | 44.046238 | -123.022026 |
| 1000 N West Street, Suite 1200 Wilmington, DE 19801, USA | [39.74717, -75.54999] | 39.74717 | -75.54999 |